# Atlanta Sitecore User Group - August 23, 2018

Tags: discussion, status-completed

**Date/Time (EST):** Thursday, August 23, 2018, 6:30 PM

**Date/Time (UTC):** Thursday, August 23, 2018, 22:30

**Location:** [Roam Buckhead](https://www.google.com/maps?f=q&hl=en&q=3365+Piedmont+Rd+NE,+Suite+1400,+Atlanta,+GA,+us), 3365 Piedmont Rd NE, Suite 1400, Atlanta, GA

**RSVP:** https://www.meetup.com/Atlanta-Sitecore/events/248747387/

**Twitter:** [@AtlantaSitecore](https://twitter.com/atlantasitecore)

[image: Atlanta Sitecore User Group]

Mark your calendars for the next Atlanta Sitecore User Group meeting on August 23rd, at 6:30 pm, at Roam in Buckhead!

Parking will be complimentary. We will be providing prepaid validations to all our guests. Dinner and drinks will be served.

### Agenda

- 6:30 - 7:00 PM: Food, drinks, and social time
- 7:00 - 7:15 PM: [Amy Winburn](https://twitter.com/SitecoreAmy) ([Arke](https://www.arke.com/)) - [Women of Sitecore](https://twitter.com/womenofsitecore)
- 7:15 - 7:50 PM: [Katie Sanford](https://www.linkedin.com/in/katie-sanford-a0425182/) & [Viktoria Shostak](https://www.linkedin.com/in/viktoria-shostak-0babb846/) ([Brainjocks](https://brainjocks.com/)) - Taming the Content Monster
- 7:50 - 8:25 PM: [Shu Jackson](https://twitter.com/sitecoreshu) & [Courtney Dean](https://www.linkedin.com/in/courtneybdean/) ([Perficient](https://www.perficient.com/)) - Glass Mapper 5
- 8:25 - 8:30 PM: Final announcements

### Presentations

#### Women of Sitecore

**Speaker:** [Amy Winburn](https://twitter.com/SitecoreAmy) - [Arke](https://www.arke.com/)

Our goal is to find out more about other women in the field, including information about your careers, issues you may be facing, and what you think a community can or should provide.

#### Taming the Content Monster: Six Strategies for Slaying Content Creation

**Speakers:** [Katie Sanford](https://www.linkedin.com/in/katie-sanford-a0425182/) and [Viktoria Shostak](https://www.linkedin.com/in/viktoria-shostak-0babb846/) - [Brainjocks](https://brainjocks.com/)

Improving the user experience is a KPI on nearly everyone’s digital scorecard these days. But have you ever considered the user experience of your content team? If authoring content were easier, would the quality of the content be better? This session will explore ways to simplify the content authoring process and improve the UX of your team. Using real-world examples, the session will show you how to accelerate content assembly and ensure that even the newest content authors can create pages quickly.

#### Glass Mapper 5

**Speakers:** [Shu Jackson](https://twitter.com/sitecoreshu) and [Courtney Dean](https://www.linkedin.com/in/courtneybdean/) - [Perficient](https://www.perficient.com/)

1. What is Glass Mapper/ORM?
2. How to use Glass Mapper
3. What's new and changed in Glass Mapper 5

Comment: Community Bulletin promotion begins on Aug 13 at 22:30